# Where is the compiler in Remix?

Tags: solidity, remix, compiler

I installed `remix-ide`.

It is able to compile contracts. So it somehow calls Solidity compiler. Where is this compiler located in the filesystem and how to use it without `remix-ide`?

Answer (score 1):

`remix-ide` uses the `remix-solidity` package which downloads the solc binary, if I read the source code correctly. If you are looking to run the solc compiler standalone, you can install it on Ubuntu by running:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install solc`

You can find more info in the documentation: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/installing-solidity.html